# How to create a column scatter plot from two different dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization, scatter-plot

I have a 1377x6 dataframe, with 2 columns of interest: "ID" and "foo"
I split the foo column into > 0.25 and < 0.25, resulting in 2 different dataframes.

I want to create a scatter plot of values from the > 0.25 dataframe and the < 0.25 dataframe.

I figured I shouldn't run into many problems if I just merged the negative column into the positive dataframe, but I was wondering **if you could create a column scatter plot using values from two different dataframes?**

I tried using
    `plt.scatter(x = greater['foo'], y = less['foo'])`
but I got a ValueError, saying that x and y must be the same size.

**Would merging the columns into one dataframe solve this problem?**

Comment: no, it would not. you are trying to plot values of the same column against each other, i.e. data from the same column on x _and_ y axis. So, without further information, it is a bit unclear how you determine which entries are mapped to each other. Further, if the number of items < and > .25 differ, plt.scatter will throw an error, like in your question. I think it is more likely that you want to plot something like `plt.scatter(greater['foo'], greater['ID'])`

Comment: the two dataseries need to have the same dimension (e.g. both 100 rows). Thats what's causing the error. Try finding a dynamic border for splitting (such as above/below median), which leads to both dataframes being same length. If dimensions match, then it doesnt matter which object the data is in.

Comment: I'm trying to make it look something like this: [link](https://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/column-scatter)
with the x axis having scatters of the greater_than values and the less_than values
The y axis would have the foo values themselves @warped

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `seaborn`, i think you want `sns.swarmplot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# generate dataframe with 100 random integers between 0 and 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0,100,100)})

# create a new column with True if value is larger than 50 and False otherwise
df['larger_than_50'] = df['a'] > 50

# make swarmplot
sns.swarmplot(x='larger_than_50', y='a', data=df)
plt.show()
```